# how to generate locust html file without UI？

Tags: python, performance-testing, locust

how to generate locust html file without UI？

```
locustfile = /mnt/locust/locustfile.py
headless = true
host = https://uat.xxx.biz
users = 1000
spawn-rate = 1
run-time = 25m
expect-workers=4
master
html=basic.html
```

I got error

> master_1  | locust: error: unrecognized arguments: --html=basic.html

#### Edit

locust 1.4.1

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8089:8089 -v $PWD:/mnt/locust tnt_locust:1.0.0 -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --headless -u 10 -r 10 --run-time 15s --html=basicNew.html
```

Same error as above.

Comment: how do you run your locust?
have you tried smth like?

`locust -f locustfile.py --headless -u 10 -r 10 --run-time 15s --html=basicNew.html`

Comment: should 'master' line after expected-workers=4 line be present?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

config file should follow all of the [document examples](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/configuration.html), key=value:

```
# master.conf in current directory
locustfile = locust_files/my_locust_file.py
headless = true
master = true
expect-workers = 5
host = ''
users = 100
spawn-rate = 10
run-time = 10s
html=base.html
```

by your example, master value has been skipped

and run it by command:

```
locust --config=master.conf
```

by the way, have tried without master and workers params?like:

```
# master.conf in current directory
locustfile = locust_files/my_locust_file.py
headless = true
host = ''
users = 10
spawn-rate = 10
run-time = 10s
html=base.html
```

also, there's opportunity to generate html file adding to cli:

```
locust -f locustfile.py --headless -u 10 -r 10 --run-time 15s --html=basicNew.html
```

By the way, it's due to 1.4.1 version of locust, it didn't have HTML report yet. only from 1.4.2 it was added:

> 1.4.2 Multiple improvements for charting including tooltips etc Added –html option to save HTML report
> [docs.locust.io/en/stable/changelog.html#id3](http://it%27s%20due%20to%201.4.1%20version%20of%20locust,%20it%20didn%27t%20have%20HTML%20report%20yet.%20only%20in%201.4.2%20was%20added:%201.4.2%20Multiple%20improvements%20for%20charting%20including%20tooltips%20etc%20Added%20%E2%80%93html%20option%20to%20save%20HTML%20report%20docs.locust.io/en/stable/changelog.html#id3%20Lots%20of%20other%20small%20fixes.%20Try%20to%20update%20version%20to%201.4.2%20or%20latest%20one%201.4.3)  Lots of other small
> fixes.

Try to update version to 1.4.2 or latest one 1.4.3

Comment: I updated the post, same error .check the edit part please.

Comment: @VidyVideni it's due to 1.4.1 version of locust, it didn't have HTML report yet.
only in 1.4.2 was added:
1.4.2
Multiple improvements for charting including tooltips etc
Added –html option to save HTML report https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/changelog.html#id3
Lots of other small fixes.
Try to update version to 1.4.2 or latest one 1.4.3